# How to use the chronometer as a countdown timer in Android

Tags: android, chronometer

I have defined a chronometer;

```
protected Chronometer chrono;
protected int baseTime;
protected int stopTime;
protected long elapsedTime;
```

My program asks questions to the user and i want to set a timer based on the user's input. I want a timer which starts at 10 to 0. How can i do that?

Also, I want to show the remaining time on the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [CountDownTImer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) instead,

```
 new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) { //Sets 10 second remaining

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextView.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

**Note : It's not possible to start Chronometer reversely because the Chronometer widget only counts up.**

Edit: From API level 24, it is possible to perform count down using chronometer via help of `Chronometer#setCountDown(true)` method.

Comment: Thank you sir! So, can i show it on the screen and set a position, size for CountDownTimer?

Comment: @EmreŞen you'll be showing It to a `TextView`. Position easily wherever you like.. And you are welcome ! –

Comment: well you need to use chronometer in notifications unless you want to update push notifications every second yourself :/ and then you rely on android +24